# Own query vars are not displayed

Tags: wp-query, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I'm trying to write a custom rewrite rule and then to a redirect based on the last part of it:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'a_add_query_vars');
add_action('init', 'a_rewrite_tags');
add_action('init', 'a_rewrite_rules');
add_action('init', 'a_download_token');

function a_rewrite_tags()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%download-token%', '([^/&]+)');
}

function a_add_query_vars($public_query_vars)
{
    $public_query_vars[] = 'download-token';
    return $public_query_vars;
}

function a_rewrite_rules()
{
    //Download
    add_rewrite_rule('^download/([^&/]*)/?', 'index.php?download-token=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

function a_download_token()
{
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    }
    global $wp_query;
    //print_r($wp_query->query_vars);

    if (!empty(get_query_var("download-token", null))) {
        //Unfortunately this won't be executed...
        error_log("SUCCESS");
        AnotherClass::download(get_query_var("download-token"));
    }
}
```

### The Problem

I verified that the rewrite rule works (with Debug bar/Query Monitor), but the `query_vars` array of the `$wp_query` object is empty.

Comment: The query hasn't been parsed yet on init action. Also note that adding a rewrite tag adds the query var automatically, that part is redundant.

Comment: @Milo Thanks so far! Which event should I use then to hook into?

Comment: @Milo nvm, I used the "parse_query" hook. Thanks for everything! I'll accept your answer as correct when you create one ;)